# How can one disable the XML editor in Eclipse for .xsd and related files?

Tags: xml, eclipse

I want to be able to double-click on an .xsd and have Eclipse open it in a text editor, but if I add a ".xsd" file association it shows up with the XML Editor as the first editor in the list and it says "(locked by 'XML (Illformed)' content type) (locked by 'XSD' content type)" etc., and under the Content Types panel the section for XML is all locked.  Eclipse is parsing my XML files all wrong and it just doesn't make sense to use the structured editor.  How do I disable it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the file extension to editor mapping in Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations.

Comment: That only means you can't remove it.  You can change the Default by pushing that button.  You might have to Add the default Text Editor to the list before doing so.

Comment: I had to restart Eclipse for it to take affect.